# zipalign' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android

I Wrote an android app.
I type zipalign myApp.apk on cmd at windows 7 and I get:

```
zipalign' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file
```

What is the problem

Comment: Run it as  `Android-SDK\tools\zipalign`

Comment: Look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048208/zipalign-command-not-found) same question solved

Answer (score 25):

`zipalign.exe` can be found in the build tools (my path in my PC is `C:\Users\[user name]\Developer\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\build-tools`), in my builds 19.1.0 and 20.0.0 folders. If you can't find it, fire up Windows Explorer and search for `zipalign.exe`, likely in `C:\`, unless you have installed in another drive.

Copy `zipalign.exe` to the tools folder, same level as build-tools (in my case, it is `C:\Users\[user name]\Developer\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools`). Once done, I could compile successfully.

Comment: I found my SDK build-tools here `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools` then select the relevant android version and add it to the PATH

Answer (score 8):

Go to

> Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign

copy the zipalign.exe into the current directory

and then run it.
Example:

[image]

[image]

Now to optimize the APK , run the following command

E:\app publish\J\JQuery Reference>zipalign -v 4 jquery-reference-unsigned.apk jq
ueryReference.apk

Answer (score 7):

An example on how to run zipalign without adding the path variable from CMD prompt:

```
C:\Users\mywindowsusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\zipalign.exe -v -p 4 my-app-unsigned.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

Answer (score 3):

You should navigate to the directory wich has the zipalign executable in it.

Comment: I have one more question: I get this error when I upload my app to the market:
You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.
You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode.

Where I can change the mood ro realse?

Comment: You should change your package name in the manifest and other files. See Android for more documentation about release mode: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile

Answer (score 3):

Zipalign.exe is located in /path/to/android/sdk/build-tools/sdk-number

In command line:

1. Navigate to the location where zipalign.exe can be found
2. Run: zipalign -v -f 4 /full/path/to/apk/unaligned-apk.apk /full/path/to/new-aligned-apk.apk

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this:

1.search for zipaligned in main search bar

2.copy it to current directory

3.run your commands without changing anything

4.it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk xxx.apk
```

instead put infront of above command

> ./

while you run it in terminal

```
\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release>./zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk xxx.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using powershell like I was, exit and use standard windows command prompt and then it will execute :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy `zipalign` exe file into the `Android\Sdk\build-tools\` folder and add path in environment variables ...

Answer (score 0):

im comming from [ionic-doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/deployment/play-store#signing-an-apk), and thiew way works form me by adding this to `PATH`

```sh
/path/to/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign
```