# Phonegap build release version locally (without Phonegap Build)

Tags: android, cordova, release, signing

i recently finished working on my first hybrid app project with phonegap. 
when it came to the open beta test i was a bit scared of the signing process. 
i read many different snippets of advice from here but also from other places in the net to get that work.

following is a step by step how to build and correctly sign a release version for the release in google play store.

hope that it helps you. cheers

---

**Phonegap Signing and Release Process**

**before you start:**

- make sure you have the java jdk in your $JAVA_HOME path
  to check it type $JAVA_HOME in your terminal and check the path for correct java path
- open the androidMainfest.xml from your android project and change *android:debuggable* in the *application*-tag to false

**1. generate a private key**

create a private key (Dont Loose it, ever!)
 - i save the key in my personal .ssh folder so all keys are at the same place 
 - it will ask you for a password and some personal details
 - make sure to replace *[key_name]* and *[key_alias]* with your keystorename and and alias (dont loose that either!)

---

```
cd /Users/[username]/.ssh
keytool -genkey -v -keyalg RSA -keystore [key_name].keystore -alias [key_alias] -keysize 2048 -validity 50000
```

---

- To Store the path to your keystore file and the key_alias for later use in this project create a new ant.properties file in the platforms/android folder and put in this:
  (change your [username], [key_name] and [key_alias] accordingly

[ant.properties] file

---

```
key.store=/Users/[username]/.ssh/[key_name].keystore
key.alias=[key_alias]
```

---

**2. build the release-unsigned.apk**

- change to the platforms android directory of your app and rund the ant comment

---

```
cd platforms/android
ant release
```

---

**3. signing the apk**

- make sure to replace [username] with your username
- replace *[key_name]* and *[key_alias]* with the key details (from step 1)
- replace *[appname]* with the name of the ...-release-unsigned.apk
- you will be asked for your keystore password (set in step 1)

---

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore /Users/[username]/.ssh/[key_name].keystore [appname]-release-unsigned.apk [key_alias]
```

---

**4. create final release apk**

- replace *[appname]* with your appname and build the final release file

---

```
zipalign -v 4 [appname]-release-unsigned.apk [appname].apk
```

---

**5. Load up your final release to google playstore**

The final app release is now found in the bin folder of your android project
its named *[appname].apk* 
upload that file with the google play developer console (https://play.google.com/apps/publish)

create a google group or google+ group and name it as the alpha/beta test group for your app. every person that is in this group can see your test version in the appstore and install it. Very handy tool instead of the complicated process for ios.

happy testing :)

Comment: At step 4 I had a problem. Zipalign wasn't recognized. As solution I navigated to the zipalign.exe which can be found here: `android-sdk\build-tools\build-tools-(sdk-number)` to run the command there. Another solution is to copy the zipalign.exe to the `android-sdk\tools`. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16099902/4815184)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...don't forget to minify your code as best you can and remove console logging on a release build

http://jscompress.com/

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: yes for sure ... best would be to use gruntjs as a task runner for that

Comment: Absolutely, never got round to doing that yet, I'd love to see cordova/phonegap incorporate some standard hooks to minify stuff