# zipalign: command not found

Tags: android, bash, ionic-framework

I'm working on Ionic project now whereby I want to `zipalign` the `android-release-unsigned.apk` file. I followed [this guide by Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html).

When I run `zipalign -v 4 /Users/zulhilmizainudin/Desktop/kl-parking/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk android-release.apk` command, I get `-bash: zipalign: command not found` error.

This is where zipalign sit in my system:

```
/Users/zulhilmizainudin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2
```

I tried to copy zipalign inside it and put it inside my Ionic project folder and run the zipalign command again. But still get the same command not found.

What should I do now?

Comment: _"I tried to copy zipalign inside it and put it inside my Ionic project folder and run the zipalign command again. But still get the same command not found."_ And what if you run `./zipalign` ?

Comment: The directory where `zipalign` is located is not in your PATH, which is why you have to specify where `zipalign` is located when you run it.

Comment: How to locate `zipalign` inside my PATH?

Comment: To add the build-tools directory to your PATH you would use something like `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/zulhilmizainudin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Solved!

1. I copied **zipalign** file from my `Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2` into my Ionic project folder
2. I add `./` in front of the zipalign command like this - `./zipalign -v 4 /Users/zulhilmizainudin/Desktop/kl-parking/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk android-release.apk`
3. Done. Now I get **android-release.apk** inside my Ionic project folder.

Thanks to Michael for the solution!

Comment: A minor suggestion is to use symbolic link, instead of copying the binary file itself.

Comment: This is the only solution. I tried 10 000 suggested solutions, only this 1 works. Thanks @Zulhilmi

Comment: in my case it didn't throw any error but I didn't get any new apk file .why ?

Answer (score 30):

If you're using **Windows**, the right way is to add path to zipalign.exe as PATH environment variable.

1. Finding where **zipalign.exe** is located in your PC, in my case this was

> C:\Users\random-username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\24.0.1

2. Then add this location as one of the entries in your [PATH environment variable](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=path%20environment%20variable%20windows%2010).

Comment: reopen command window after perform the settings to take new effect

Comment: Same if you're working with the cli within vscode, close them **all** before reopening and running the command again

Answer (score 19):

To avoid specifying or navigating to your sdk/build-tools/* directories each time you intend to build release version, you can simply add the path to your environment variable.

> $ sudo nano ~/.bash_profile

copy and paste the below:

> export PATH=${PATH}:/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2

You can then save and exit:

> <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> // to save to file
>   <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> // to close the file
>   $ source ~/.bash_profile

You can then run your `zipalign` command from your project CLI directory.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is the easiest way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 6):

**Windows**

the right way is to add path to zipalign.exe as PATH environment variable.

Finding where zipalign.exe is located in your PC, in my case this was

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\29.0.2
```

Then add this location as one of the entries in your [PATH environment variable](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/).

**MAC**

To avoid specifying or navigating to your SDK/build-tools/* directories each time you intend to build a release version, you can simply add the path to your environment variable.

```
$ sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

copy and paste the below:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2
```

You can then save and exit:

```
control + o // to save to file
control + x // to close the file
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

You can then run your zipalign command from your project CLI directory.

Answer (score 5):

if you are making ionic release build then you can make build.json file on your app's root folder with these information given below

```
{
"android": {
   "release": {
   "keystore": "Your keystore",
   "storePassword": "password",
   "alias": "alias name",
   "password" : "password",
   "keystoreType": ""
    }
}  }
```

make sure that you can place your keystore on your app's root folder or provide full path of your keystore at keystore object

now just you can run this command as below

```
ionic cordova build android --release
```

this command automatically find your build.json and make signed release build.

Comment: What should be included into the `keystore`, and the `keystoreType` variable?

Comment: make your keystore file and in build.json set that keystore file name and keystoreType is jks or Keystore as per your keystore file

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Mac. Install and run Android Studio (important to start it one time).
Then find zipalign:

```
find ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools -name "zipalign"
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved!

I copied zipalign file as Michael Said
( from my Library/Android/SDK/build-tools/28.0.3 into my Ionic project folder)

BUT when I run

```
./zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk botellamovil.apk
```

I got

```
./zipalign: ERROR while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: **No such file or directory**
```

So, I also copied **lib & lib64** files, and then it Works!!

I hope it will be helpful :) (and sorry for my English)

Answer (score 2):

You should do (align, sign, and verify)for APK.
In mac, you should do the following steps:

***A - Aligning APK:***

1- you should locate **zipalign** your build tools inside android SDK:

```
/Users/mina/Downloads/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/zipalign
```

2- you should locate your **unsigned apk**:

```
 /Users/mina/Desktop/apks/app_unsigned.apk
```

3- you should run command contains:

zipalign_path + -v -p 4 + unsigned_apk_path + output_aligned_apk_name

```
/Users/mina/Downloads/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/zipalign -v -p 4 
/Users/mina/Desktop/apks/app-unsigned.apk app_aligned.apk
```

4-  output is Verification successful

***B - Signing APK:***

1- you should locate **apksigner** your build tools inside android SDK:

```
/Users/mina/Downloads/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/apksigner
```

2- you should locate your release-Keystore in your pc:

```
/Users/mina/Desktop/keys/release-Keystore.jks
```

3- you should run command contains:

apksigner_path + **sign --ks** + release-Keystore_path + **--out** + output_signed_apk_name + from_aligned_apk_name

```
/Users/mina/Downloads/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/apksigner sign --ks 
/Users/mina/Desktop/keys/release-keystore.jks                                                    
 --out app_signed.apk app_aligned.apk
```

4- enter your key store password

**C- Verifying APK:**

1- run the following command : apksigner_path + verify + app_signed.apk

```
/Users/mina/Downloads/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/apksigner verify 
app_signed.apk
```

Notes: you may find some warnings:

```
 WARNING: META-INF/....
```

Here is some description about that:

[Apk Metainfo Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122546/apk-metainfo-warning)

In practice, these files are not important, they're mostly versions of libraries you depend on, so even if someone modified those, it wouldn't have any impact on your app. That's why it's only a warning: those files in your APK can be modified by someone else while still pretending that the APK is signed by you, but those files don't really matter.

**D- find your signed APK:**

```
/Users/mina/app_signed.apk
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by making the zipalign path an environment variable:

```
export ZIPALIGN_PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/zipalign
```

Then I replaced `zipalign` with `$ZIPALIGN_PATH` in the script I was trying to run

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into several problems since I installed Kali from the USB live installer.
I found out that I needed to add this into my **`sources.list`** file in `/etc/apt` folder.
Just replace the content of `sources.list` with:

```html
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main
```