# APK Signature Scheme V2 now required : Api 30

Tags: android, google-play, android-api-levels

Just received an email from google play update that contains informations about the new target sdk requirements starting August 2021. it also mention this :

> Apps that target **Android 11 (API level 30)** that are currently only
> signed using APK Signature Scheme v1 must now also be signed using APK
> Signature Scheme v2 or higher. Users can't install or update apps that
> are only signed with APK Signature Scheme v1 on devices that run
> **Android 11.**

I'm quite confused , is this meaning that actually device running android 11 won't be able to install apk with signature scheme V1 ? Or it won't be able starting August 2021?

Comment: My interpretation is: 1) apps with a `targetSdkVersion` of 30 or higher won't be installable on devices running Android 11 if you only sign with signature scheme V1, and 2) by november 2021 any updates that you release for your existing apps must have a `targetSdkVersion` of 30 or higher (for new apps the dealine is august 2021).

Comment: @Michael so you mean that only app that target sdk 30 won't be installed on device running android 11 with signature scheme v1 ? for you second point it's obvious yeah

Comment: The signature V2 requirement is listed [on a page](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11) specifically about apps targetting Android 11.

Comment: @Michael yeah i know , and this is what got me confused :( !

Comment: @MontresorXPL what you mean ? please read my question again !